# One checkbox at a time

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have a button that, when clicked, copies a specific cell depending on which checkbox is checked.

Can anyone suggest a way to change it so that only one checkbox can be checked at any one time?

Thanks in advance!

```
Public Sub CopyButton_Click()

    if(CheckBox1.Value = true) then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").copy
    end if

    if(CheckBox2.Value = true) then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").copy
    end if

    'copy the chunk above for more check boxes

End Sub
```

Comment: use radio buttons...

Answer (score 0):

You can be a bit sneaky about it and simply use exit subs and msgboxes, like this

```
Public Sub CopyButton_Click()

    If (CheckBox1.Value = True) and (CheckBox2.Value = True) Then
        MsgBox "Only one box can be checked at a time"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf  (CheckBox1.Value = true) Then
         ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Copy
    End if
End Sub
```

That should do the trick, right?

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer as it does what you're asking for